# QML scope: property binding in child object failing

Tags: scope, qt-creator, qml, property-binding

I'm new to QML and ran into a scope problem while going a button tutorial. I solved it but I don't understand why the code didn't work in the first place:

### Problem

The following code gives Runtime reference errors when the button is hovered over:

*main_broken.qml*

```
    import QtQuick 2.0
    import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

    ApplicationWindow {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Button Tester")

        Rectangle {
                id: simpleButton
                height: 75
                width: 150
                property color buttonColor: "light blue"
                property color onHoverColor: "gold"
                property color borderColor: "white"

                onButtonClick: {
                        console.log(buttonLabel.text + " clicked")
                }

                signal buttonClick()



                Text {
                    id: buttonLabel
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "button label"
                }

                MouseArea {
                    id: buttonMouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: buttonClick()
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    onEntered: parent.border.color = onHoverColor
                    onExited: parent.border.color = borderColor
                }

                color: buttonMouseArea.pressed ? Qt.darker(buttonColor, 1.5) : buttonColor
                scale: buttonMouseArea.pressed ? 0.99 : 1
        }

    }
```

*errors:*

```
qrc:///main.qml:37: ReferenceError: onHoverColor is not defined
qrc:///main.qml:38: ReferenceError: borderColor is not defined
qrc:///main.qml:37: ReferenceError: onHoverColor is not defined
qrc:///main.qml:35: ReferenceError: buttonClick is not defined
```

### Solution

Solved by just moving the property bindings and signal-slot into the Application window object as follows:

*main_fixed.qml*

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Button Tester")

    property color buttonColor: "light blue"
    property color onHoverColor: "gold"
    property color borderColor: "white"

    onButtonClick: {
            console.log(buttonLabel.text + " clicked")
    }

    signal buttonClick()

    //etc
```

### Questions

Why is it not possible to leave the property bindings within the Rectangle child of the ApplicationWindow object?

What if you wanted to have properties exclusive only to the rectangle (e.g. colour), but that used some of the properties of the ApplicationWindow (e.g. text size)?

---

I am new to coding and stack overflow (this is my first post). I've tried to ask my question in the clearest way possible, but please let me know if it's not up to par with stack overflow's standards and what I must do to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scope in QML is easy, maybe weird, but easy :

When you use an identifier, lets say `foo` in a var binding, QML engine search in this order :

- an **object** in the **current file** that has `foo` as its ID
- an **object** in **global scope** (main QML file) that has `foo` as its ID
- a **property** in **current object** that is called `foo`
- a **property** in the **root object** of current component (current file) that is called `foo`

If it does not find it, it throws `ReferenceError`.

And no, immediate parent or child is **not in the scope**. That can seem weird, but that's the way it works.

If you need an out-of-scope variable to be referenced, just use an ID before it : if the object is called `foo` and has a property named `bar`, you can reference `foo.bar` wherever you wan't in the file.

Hope it helps.